# Importing Swift framework in Xcode - where to put "import" instructions?

Tags: swift

I am trying to import an existing SDK for ClickSend (https://github.com/ClickSend/clicksend-swift) into my existing iOS Swift project in Xcode, but the installation doesn't say much (at least not for me that comes from Visual Studio and C#).

This is the installation instruction:

> Put the package under your project folder and add the following in
>   import:
>
> ```
> "./clicksend-swift"
> ```

I can't seem to find any places called "import" where I can add `./clicksend-swift`. I have been trying to add the files/folders to my project, but it doesn't compile (can't find the Alamo framework)

I guess this is something that is *very* trival and everyone understands, since the installation is so short and there are no Google results for doing a simple import project.

Comment: I assume it just means download it, and then drag it into your Xcode project under `<Project Name> -> <Project Name>` (yellow folder underneath blue icon).

Comment: There are two ways to add a package to your project. One way is the one you are trying and the second way is to use [cocapods](https://cocoapods.org/) if its in that package manager, if so you have to add it by `import`.

Comment: Yes, i thought so myself, but it doesnt compile : Getting error No such module 'Alamofire' from the library when compiling

Comment: @Blasanka : Thanks for trying to help .     So this should be the solution. add the folders to my project and add the import text somewhere in the xcworkspace file ?

Comment: Have you tried to use carthage to do this? brew install carthage, create a file name cartfile and add github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.7.2 without the quotes on the file. Next, carthage update. Of course that you need to change the Alamofire/Alamofire with the owner of the repository and the repository itself.

Comment: I agree with @Igor. The github folder has a cartfile so obviously you are supposed to be using carthage.

Answer (score 0):

The ClickSend team has now updated library and installation instructions, so everything is clear on how to install the library.  :)